# How to get rid of the already searched list

Tags: magento-1.9, search

When i go to type in a product code as they all start with the same two letters i get a big long list of already searched for products, How can i get rid of this list as i don't like the way it looks on my site. We have Blast Search Lucene installed so i asked them but they said it was one of the magento core functions that was showing this list.

What file would i have to edit so that this list is made or doesn't appear

Comment: Are you referring to `ajax search suggestion` or your browser autocomplete?

Comment: it maybe the auto complete because it shows products that have been search fro before, i have added a screenshot to my question to show you what i mean

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just edit `app/design/frontend/{package}/{theme}/template/catalogsearch/form.mini.phtml` and remove these lines:

```
    <div id="search_autocomplete" class="search-autocomplete"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
        var searchForm = new Varien.searchForm('search_mini_form', 'search', '<?php echo $this->__('Search entire store here...') ?>');
        searchForm.initAutocomplete('<?php echo $catalogSearchHelper->getSuggestUrl() ?>', 'search_autocomplete');
    //]]>
    </script>
```